# How to add an Exception Handler for an exception type that could be custom or default

Tags: java, spring

I have a use case where for certain exception's that are normally thrown by a web framework that I can override the value by using my own `MyCustomException` object.

```
@ExceptionHandler({SomeWebFrameworkException.class})
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(MyCustomException exception) { ... }
```

However, if I want an exception handler to be able to be able to accept my custom exception then, I would need to cover all cases of this web framework error being thrown. Is there a way to somehow make it accept MyCustomException as input otherwise just default to a normal Exception ? If I just use a simple `Exception` as the input then, it would end up getting treated as the SomeWebFrameworkException instead of my own.

```
@ExceptionHandler({SomeWebFrameworkException.class})
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleException(Exception exception1, MyCustomException exception2) { ... }
```

Comment: Could it not work is you define an exception as parent class and make extend the parent exception to make other exception, then you only need to handle the parent exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple exception handling methods defined, similarly to catch-blocks

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleMyCustomException(MyCustomException exception) { ... }

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleGenericException(Exception exception) { ... }
```

Comment: I can't do it like this `@ExceptionHandler(MyCustomException.class)` where I have the exception handler listen for my custom exception because its not picking up my custom exception. When I throw `MyCustomException` at runtime during construction of an object it gets converted to a `WebFrameworkException` instead.

Comment: I see, if that's the case then you could create an exception handler for WebFrameworkException, check whether e.getCause() points to your custom exception, otherwise - re-throw it again without any handling.